# c# Разделение строки на подстроки и запись в List<string>

Tags: c#, list

У меня есть длинная зашифрованная строка, в которой хранятся важные параметры, разделённые между друг другом словом (keyWord = "1231sffqs"). Мне нужно обратно разделить все эти параметры и записать отдельно в List.

Я делаю это с помощью метода:

```
public List<string> GetList()
        {
            string BigDATA = info.BigDATA;
            List<string> list = new List<string>();
            foreach (string word in BigDATA.Split(new string[] { keyWord }, StringSplitOptions.None))
                list.Add(word);

            return list;
        }
```

Суть вопроса: Можно ли это сделать как-то иначе? Интересуюсь просто ради спортивного интереса

UPD:
предложили такой вариант:

```
 public List<string> GetList()
        {
            string BigDATA = info.BigDATA;
            List<string> list = BigDATA.Split(new string[] { keyWord }, StringSplitOptions.None).ToList();

            return list;
        }
```

или вообще вот такой вариант (аналогично предыдущему работает)

```
public List<string> GetList() => info.BigDATA.Split(new string[] { keyWord }, StringSplitOptions.None).ToList();
```

Comment: Можно вызвать ToList на результате Split

Comment: Правильнее всего, чтобы функция `GetList` возвращала не `List<string>`, заполненный осмысленными данными объект. Вам понадобится класс наподобие `record Parameters(string Password, int Length, DateTime Expiry);`

Comment: Кстати, отличная идея. Спасибо огромное =)